# How to realize the computation of the expectation value of hamiltonian matrix through Fortran

Tags: fortran, lapack, blas, eigenvector

I want to compute the expectation value of an operator (A), which is a `4 by 4` complex matrix. I have the Eigen vector matrix (B), which is also a `4 by 4` matrix,as well.

I want to use Fortran to write a code and to compute the expectation value of this operator with the Eigen vector ().

Is there any subroutine or function in `LAPACK` or `BLAS` libraries doing such calculation? I found a subroutine, named `GEMV` in the `BLAS` library but it only calculates the multiplication of matrix with a vector.

Comment: Welcome, please tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions Please read [ask] and pay attention what kinds of questions are on-topic and off-topic here. Finding or recommending a library function is off-topic. Instead show us your code and describe what you have tried.

Comment: You should also explain what "expectation value" is.

Comment: Dear Vladimir, Thank you for the reply. The expectation value of an operator is written in the following format <m|A|n>. where, A is the operator (4 by 4 complex matrix); |n> is the Eigen vector, which is 4 by 1 complex matrix; <m| is the transpose and conjugate of Eigen vector |m>. Both |m> and |n> are 4 by 1 Eigen vector. Is there any subroutine/function in BLAS or LAPACK or other libraries do such calculation? Thank  you.

Comment: Don't put in comments any material which (a) belongs in the question and (b) depends on formatting for clarity and readability.  Edit your question.  Somewhere on your screen there is an icon for editing, maybe even the word 'edit', try clicking.

Comment: Hint: There is nothing that will do it directly, but you can do it in two stages. And the Fortran intrinsics Matmul and Conjg will be an easier way than BLAS, and for such small matrices you won't notice any performance difference.

Comment: Dear Ian, Thank you for the answer. If the operator (A) is a 10 by 10 complex matrix and |m> and |n> are both10 by 1 complex vector. Is there any other faster subroutine/function in the library to do such calculation?

Comment: For such tiny matrices for operations with such a low compute intensity in all honesty hand crafted loops will probably be the way to go if you really need the performance - subroutine call overhead will kill optimisation in the routine. What are you REALLY trying to do? Don't comment - put it in the question.